# How to preserve ui-router parameters on browser refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, page-refresh

am using angular ui-router to manage states of my SPA.
I have this route:

```
    .state('index.administration.security.roleEdit', {
                url: '/roleEdit',
                templateUrl: 'app/administration/security/role/roleEdit.html',
                controller: 'roleEditCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'roleEditCtrl',
                params: { data: null },
                resolve: {
                    role: function ($stateParams) {
                        return angular.fromJson($stateParams.data);
                    },
                    modules: function (securityService) {
                        return securityService.getAllModules();
                    }                       
                }
            })
```

Also, I'm passing 'data' parameter as json object to the state.
Now when i first load this state, everything is fine.
But when i do browser refresh (F5 key) the $stateParams.data is null in the resolve function of the state.

How can I solve this?
I see these possible solutions:
1. persist somehow parameters
2. override browser refresh (don't know how) to stop the browser refreshing the app.
3. on refresh goto other sibling state.

Please help

**UPDATE**
Ok, I set data like this:

```
vm.editRole = function(roleId){
     var role = dataService.getRoleById(roleId).then(function(result){
           $state.go('roleEdit', {data:angular.toJson(result)});
           });
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
The roleEdit Controller looks like this:

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.administration').controller('roleEdit', 
    ['role','modules', '$scope', 'securityService', '$state', roleEditCtrl]);

    function roleEditCtrl('role', 'modules',$scope, securityService, $state){
        var vm = this;
        vm.roles = roles;
        vm.originalRole = angular.copy(role);
        vm.modules=modules;
        vm.saveChanges = _saveChanges;
        vm.cancel = _cancel;

        return vm;

        function _saveChanges(){
            securityService.UpdateRole(vm.role).then(function(result){
                $staste.go('^.roles');
            }
        }

        function _cancel(){
            vm.role = angular.copy(vm.originalRole);
            $sscope.roleEditForm.$setPristine();            
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Have you considered local storage?

Comment: How do you set \data\?

Comment: #Anid Monsour - I am considering anything right now. Local storage is one option but then i must find a place for clearing it.

Comment: #maurycy - I have updated the question, see UPDATE

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, leaving this here in case someone else needs it. Solved it by using `localStorage`.

I've set this as a part of app's `run` method

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {
    localStorage.setItem('__stateName', toState.name);
});
```

Now, depending on your app's structure you might want to consider putting this someplace else, but in my case I had parent `AppController` surrounding all child controllers, so this part of the code went there.

```
var previousState = localStorage.getItem('__stateName');
previousState && $state.go(previousState) || $state.go(<SOME_OTHER_ROUTE>);
```

Basically, when user hits browser refresh, AppController get initialized from the start (before child controllers), firing the state transition immediately if there was one. Otherwise, you'd go to some other state of yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from option 2. You don't want to mess up a browser's expected behavior.

Maybe you could refactor your data into your resolve object ala:

```
resolve: {
           role: function ($stateParams) {
               return angular.fromJson($stateParams.data);
           },
           modules: function (securityService) {
               return securityService.getAllModules();
           },
           data: function (dataService) {
               return dataService.retrieveStoredData();
           }
```

Where your dataService would be a service you use to store that data if it really is that important (through cookies or localstorage).

There is no reasonable way to expect that field to be populated on browser refresh if you previously executed javascript to pass stateful values to it.

Comment: Me to, I would like to stay away from option 2.
So in your solution i would need to get the data from server, and then put it into some local storage then in dataService.retrieveStoredData get this data from the local storage. Where should i delete this data from local storage then? (on statechange? or somewhere else)

Comment: I'm guessing there are a few places, the controller is one place, of course you could also add that

Comment: Ok, I aded the roleEdit controller code in update 2.