# AngularJS ui-router inconsistently behaving on manual refresh

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, page-refresh

On an application my team and I are working on, we're observing some inconsistent behavior.  When a user performs a browser refresh, the refresh button fully refreshes the page including UI state...but only does that up to a certain route.

Our App starts on the `/Home` route, which sets up the overall application, as well as the component hierarchy.  The user proceeds to `A.A`, `A.B`, `A.C`, which all function fine.  `B.A` works fine as well.

Then, trouble.  If you perform a browser refresh from `B.B` or `B.C`, you get returned to `B.A`.  We expect that the end-user would be returned to `B.B` or `B.C` if they refresh from those pages.

**Routes.ts**

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('Home',
        {
            url: '/Home',
            templateUrl: 'App/Home/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'
        })
        .state('A',
        {
            url: '/A',
            templateUrl: 'app/A/A.html',
            controller: 'aCtrl',
            controllerAs: '$ctrl'
        })
            .state('A.A',
            {
                url: '/A.A',
                component: 'aPartA'
            })
            .state('A.B',
            {
                url: '/A.B',
                component: 'aPartB'
            })
            .state('A.C',
            {
                url: '/A.C',
                component: 'aPartC'
            })
        .state('B',
        {
            url: '/B',
            component: 'b'
        })
            .state('B.A',
            {
                url: '/B.A',
                component: 'bPartA'
            })
            // Beyond this part, oddness starts...
            .state('B.B',
            {
                url: '/B.B',
                component: 'bPartB'
            })
            .state('B.C',
            {
                url: '/B.C',
                component: 'bPartC'
            });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true});
```

The way we actually perform our routing, is using a component!

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<order-navigation validate-view="$ctrl.validate(someForm)"
     previous-route="A.C"
     previous-button-text="previous"
     next-route="B.A"
     next-button-text="continue">
</order-navigation>
```

**Order Navigation Component Controller:**

```
export class OrderNavigationCtrl implements angular.IController {
    //#region Variables / Properties

    public nextRoute: string;
    public previousRoute: string;
    public nextButtonText: string;
    public previousButtonText: string;
    public validateView : () => boolean;

    //#endregion Variables / Properties

    //#region Constructor

    public static $inject: string[] = ['$state', '$window'];
    constructor(
        private $state: angular.ui.IStateService,
        private $window: angular.IWindowService) {
    }

    public $onInit(): void {

    }

    //#endregion Constructor

    //#region Methods

    public navigatePrevious(route: string): void {
        if (route.search('www') > 0)
            this.$window.open(route, '_self');
        else
            this.$state.go(route);
    }
    public navigateNext(route: string): void {
        if (this.validateView())
            this.$state.go(route);
    }

    //#endregion Methods
}
```

I've checked each page's HTML, and found no typos that would cause B.B or B.C to redirect to B.A.  As we're using a common component, I would expect that if the flaw were in the component controller, it would affect all pages equally, and cause any page refresh to fall back to a common point, which is not the case.

**Questiosn:**
A: What's causing B.B and B.C to redirect to B.A, instead of themselves?
B: In what way can I change this to ensure that B.B and B.C redirect to themselves?

**Possible Workaround:**
One thing my research has suggested that I can do is to [use `localStorage` and `.run()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33177481/how-to-preserve-ui-router-parameters-on-browser-refresh) to cache the UI router state.  I would like to avoid this, because ideally this routing should 'just work'; we're not doing anything special.  If there is something we're doing incorrectly in this, I also need to know what it is, so that my team and I don't do that incorrect thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the 'B' 'trunk' route was incorrect.  It should be:

```
.state('B', {
    url: '/B',
    templateUrl: 'app/A/A.html',
    controller: 'aCtrl',
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'
})
    .state('B.A', {
        // ...Other B substates here...
    })
```

It appears that, defining a 'trunk' view as a component has some awkward relationships with the UI router setup.  Instead, a trunk view should always be defined in a more classic manner, with the URL, controller/controller as setup defined.  When this happens, child component states can work in the manner that we expect.